# Transforming string column to specific data.frame

Tags: r, string, text, tidyverse, splitstackshape

**Desired Output**

Need the following output

```
df2 <-
  data.frame(
    v1 = c(1100001, 1100002, 1100003, 1100004, 1100005)
  , v2 = c("A R", "W R", "A K", "M", "A C")
  , v3 = c("P", "G P", "G P", "P", "P")
  , v4 = c(110, 161, 129, 132, "Absent")
  , v5 = c(55, 80.5, 64.5, 66,  "Absent")
    )
df2

       v1  v2  v3     v4     v5
1 1100001 A R   P    110     55
2 1100002 W R G P    161   80.5
3 1100003 A K G P    129   64.5
4 1100004   M   P    132     66
5 1100005 A C   P Absent Absent
```

Here is my original `data.frame`.

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(value = c(
"1100001     A R                P             110    55", 
"1100002     W R                 G P 161    80.5", 
"1100003     A K                  G P 129    64.5", 
"1100004     M                      P             132    66",
"1100005     A C                     P             Absent    Absent"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.frame")
)

df1

                                                              value
1            1100001     A R                P             110    55
2                   1100002     W R                 G P 161    80.5
3                  1100003     A K                  G P 129    64.5
4        1100004     M                      P             132    66
5 1100005     A C                     P             Absent    Absent
```

Used `cSplit` function from `splitstackshape`, but could not manage to get the required output. Any points.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(indt = df1, splitCols = "value", sep = " ")

   value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 value_6 value_7
1: 1100001       A       R       P     110      55      NA
2: 1100002       W       R       G       P     161    80.5
3: 1100003       A       K       G       P     129    64.5
4: 1100004       M       P     132      66      NA      NA
5: 1100005       A       P  Absent  Absent      NA      NA
```

Comment: What is the rule to separate "G P 161" into two variables. Also, are there tabs or spaces in between the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Assuming the rule for separation are: a) more than one space b) numbers follwing a letter and space are to be split

2.We make sure all soon to be varibles are separated by more than one space (using `gsub` to replace **one** space **between a letter and a number** with two spaces)

3.Then we use `tidyr::separate` to separate the string into variables using **two or more spaces** as deliminiator

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(value = gsub("([A-z])( )([0-9])", "\\1  \\3", value)) %>% 
  separate(value, c(paste0("v", 1:5)),"[ ]{2,}")
```

Returns:

> ```
>        v1  v2  v3     v4     v5
> 1 1100001 A R   P    110     55
> 2 1100002 W R G P    161   80.5
> 3 1100003 A K G P    129   64.5
> 4 1100004   M   P    132     66
> 5 1100005   A   P Absent Absent
> ```

## Edit

Regarding the new constraint that was not included in the original example (only one space between a number and a letter):

Suggested solution:

We just repeat the command for adding an extra space with "reversed" regex. So that any single space between a number and a letter will get an extra space and will in then be separated by the `separate` call

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(value = gsub("([A-z])( )([0-9])", "\\1  \\3", value)) %>% 
  mutate(value = gsub("([0-9])( )([A-z])", "\\1  \\3", value)) %>% 
  separate(value, c(paste0("v", 1:5)),"[ ]{2,}")
```

Comment: Thanks @dario for your answer. Third column is missing is missing some part.

Comment: So sorry, of course you are right ! Also the first digit was missing on the same rows... I fixed the regex, now it works as intended!

Comment: Your code gives output very close to required for my original data. However, for some rows, the same between starring number and letters is one space like  `1100006 B R`. Any thoughts

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've updated the answer to account for the new constraint

Answer (score 1):

We assume that a new field starts after two or more spaces or one space followed by a digit where the digit is the start of the next field.  Replace such separators with a comma and then use `read.table` with `sep=","`

```
df1$value |>
  gsub(pattern = "  +| (?=\\d)", replacement = ",", perl = TRUE) |>
  textConnection(name = "") |>
  read.table(sep = ",")
```

giving this data.frame:

```
       V1  V2  V3     V4     V5
1 1100001 A R   P    110     55
2 1100002 W R G P    161   80.5
3 1100003 A K G P    129   64.5
4 1100004   M   P    132     66
5 1100005   A   P Absent Absent
```

### Session Log

```
> df1 <-
+   structure(list(value = c(
+ "1100001     A R                P             110    55", 
+ "1100002     W R                 G P 161    80.5", 
+ "1100003     A K                  G P 129    64.5", 
+ "1100004     M                      P             132    66",
+ "1100005     A C                     P             Absent    Absent"
+ )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.frame")
+ )
> 
> df2 <-
+   data.frame(
+     v1 = c(1100001, 1100002, 1100003, 1100004, 1100005)
+   , v2 = c("A R", "W R", "A K", "M", "A C")
+   , v3 = c("P", "G P", "G P", "P", "P")
+   , v4 = c(110, 161, 129, 132, "Absent")
+   , v5 = c(55, 80.5, 64.5, 66,  "Absent")
+     )
> 
> df2a <- df1$value |>
+   gsub(pattern = "  +| (?=\\d)", replacement = ",", perl = TRUE) |>
+   textConnection(name = "") |>
+   read.table(sep = ",")
> 
> all(df2 == df2a)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: My bad. I had typo in `df1` which corrected. After correction the given code throws the error. Any thoughts. please.

Comment: Not for me.  I added the session log at the end of the answer. It does not throw an error and all elements of df2a are equal to the corresponding elements of df2.